# Difference between defining an attribute in the __init__ function parameters or just initializing it the block without setting it as a parameter

Tags: python

I'm not sure if you need to add a parameter to the **init** function before you initialize it or if you can initialize it without having it as a parameter first.

Is there a difference when writing this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.placeholder=placeholder
```

and this:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, placeholder):
        self.placeholder=placeholder
```

Comment: The difference is that the 1st one doesn't work unless you have a global variable called `placeholder` which would only make sense if you're using that global as a module wide default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, it will throw a `NameError: name 'placeholder' is not defined` when `Test().__init__()` is called, unless placeholder is an already defined global variable.

When you initialize an object by writing something like `test_object = Test()`, the `__init__()` function is called. If you have `placeholder` in the function signature, you can pass in a value i.e. `test_object = Test("placeholder string")` and in the second case, this will set `test_object.placeholder` to "placeholder string". If you try to do the same thing with the function signature in the first example, it will raise a `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The second will actually raise an error.

You need to pass the `placeholder` argument to the `__init__` in order to have access to it.

`__init__` works like any other function, so you need to declare its arguments inside the function parenthesis.